# Clojure - in a vector of hashmaps return the lowest hashmap where two keys match

Tags: clojure, hashmap

I have a vector of hashmaps with a format similar to the following:

```
[{:a 1 :b 2} {:a 3 :b 4} {:a 1 :b 6} {:a 3 :b 9} {:a 5 :b 1} {:a 6 :b 1}]
```

I would like to filter out the lowest `:b` value for matching `:a` values, so if two `:a` values are the same e.g. `{:a 1 :b 2}`,`{:a 1 :b 6}` it should return: `{:a 1 :b 2}` as 2 is lower than 6

So for the vector above I would like to get:

```
[{:a 1 :b 2} {:a 3 :b 4} {:a 5 :b 1} {:a 6 :b 1}]
```

I have tried a few things but I am a bit stuck, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What did you try? where are you getting stuck?

Comment: You can find a good explanation of comparitors (the generic version of what you want) on the ClojureDocs.org website: http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/sorted-set-by

Comment: @Shlomi I tried something like this: `(apply min-key :b (filter #(= (:a %) 3) list))` which finds the minimum value for `:b` in the list by filtering out all values where `:a` = 3 but I was having manually type in the `:a` value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your original direction was correct. You only missed the grouping part:

```
(def test [{:a 1 :b 2} {:a 3 :b 4} {:a 1 :b 6} {:a 3 :b 9} {:a 5 :b 1} {:a 6 :b 1}])

(defn min-map [m]
  (map (partial apply min-key :b) (vals (group-by :a m))))

(min-map test)
=> ({:a 1, :b 2} {:a 3, :b 4} {:a 5, :b 1} {:a 6, :b 1})
```

First we [group](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/group-by) the the list of maps by the key `:a`, and extract the values of it. We then examine each group and find the smallest value using [min-key](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/min-key) by key `:b`

Comment: thanks for that, I assume the performance of doing it this way would be better than going through the list twice as I am doing in my current solution

Comment: You can test the performance for yourself with [critirium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium). I believe this is a little more idiomatic than your solution, but its really up to you!

Answer (score -1):

So I thought about it for a bit and I now have an answer (albeit not a very good one):

```
(defn contains [a vect]
  (apply min-key :b(filter #(= (:a %) (:a a))vect))
  )

(defn starter []
  (let [tester [{:a 1 :b 2} {:a 3 :b 4} {:a 1 :b 6} {:a 3 :b 9} {:a 5 :b 1} {:a 6 :b 1}]]
    (vec(distinct(map #(contains % tester)tester)))
)
)
```

Thanks for everyones help, If you have any critiques or a better solution please post it.

Answer (score -1):

With the dependency

```
[tupelo "0.1.68"]
```

we can write the following code.  I left in lots of `spy` expressions so

```
(ns clj.core
  (:use tupelo.core)
  (:require [clojure.core               :as clj]
            [schema.core                :as s]
            [tupelo.types               :as tt]
            [tupelo.schema              :as ts]
  ))

; Prismatic Schema type definitions
(s/set-fn-validation! true)   ; #todo add to Schema docs

(def data [ {:a 1 :b 2} {:a 3 :b 4} {:a 1 :b 6} {:a 3 :b 9} {:a 5 :b 1} {:a 6 :b 1} ] )

(defn accum-smallest-b-entries
  [cum-map-a2b 
      ; A map where both keys and vals are simple 1-entry maps
      ; like:   {:a 1} -> {:b 2}
      ;         {:a 2} -> {:b 9}
   new-a-b-map
      ; next entry, like {:a 1 :b 2}
  ]
  (newline)
  (println "---------------------------------")
  (let [new-a-map   (select-keys new-a-b-map [:a] )  ; like {:a 1}
        _ (spyx new-a-map)
        new-b-map   (select-keys new-a-b-map [:b] )  ; like {:b 2}
        _ (spyx new-b-map)
        curr-b-map  (get cum-map-a2b new-a-map)
        _ (spyx curr-b-map)
        next-b-map  (if (or (nil? curr-b-map)
                            (< (grab :b new-b-map) (grab :b curr-b-map)))
                      new-b-map 
                      curr-b-map)
        _ (spyx next-b-map)
  ]
    (spyx (assoc cum-map-a2b new-a-map next-b-map))))

(def a2b-map (reduce accum-smallest-b-entries {} data))
(spyx a2b-map)

(defn combine-keyvals-from-a2b-map
  [cum-result
      ; final result like:  [ {:a 1 :b 2}
      ;                       {:a 2 :b 9} ]
   a2b-entry
      ; next entry from a2b-map like [ {:a 5} {:b 1} ]
   ]
  (newline)
  (println "combine-keyvals-from-a2b-map")
  (println "---------------------------------")
  (spyx cum-result)
  (spyx a2b-entry)
  (let [combined-ab-map (glue (first a2b-entry) (second a2b-entry)) 
        _ (spyx combined-ab-map)
        new-result      (append cum-result combined-ab-map)
        _ (spyx new-result)
        ]
    new-result))

(def a-and-b-map (reduce combine-keyvals-from-a2b-map [] a2b-map))
(spyx a-and-b-map)

(defn -main [] )
```

Running the code we get:

```
---------------------------------
new-a-map => {:a 1}
new-b-map => {:b 2}
curr-b-map => nil
next-b-map => {:b 2}
(assoc cum-map-a2b new-a-map next-b-map) => {{:a 1} {:b 2}}

---------------------------------
new-a-map => {:a 3}
new-b-map => {:b 4}
curr-b-map => nil
next-b-map => {:b 4}
(assoc cum-map-a2b new-a-map next-b-map) => {{:a 1} {:b 2}, {:a 3} {:b 4}}

---------------------------------
new-a-map => {:a 1}
new-b-map => {:b 6}
curr-b-map => {:b 2}
next-b-map => {:b 2}
(assoc cum-map-a2b new-a-map next-b-map) => {{:a 1} {:b 2}, {:a 3} {:b 4}}

---------------------------------
new-a-map => {:a 3}
new-b-map => {:b 9}
curr-b-map => {:b 4}
next-b-map => {:b 4}
(assoc cum-map-a2b new-a-map next-b-map) => {{:a 1} {:b 2}, {:a 3} {:b 4}}

---------------------------------
new-a-map => {:a 5}
new-b-map => {:b 1}
curr-b-map => nil
next-b-map => {:b 1}
(assoc cum-map-a2b new-a-map next-b-map) => {{:a 1} {:b 2}, {:a 3} {:b 4}, {:a 5} {:b 1}}

---------------------------------
new-a-map => {:a 6}
new-b-map => {:b 1}
curr-b-map => nil
next-b-map => {:b 1}
(assoc cum-map-a2b new-a-map next-b-map) => {{:a 1} {:b 2}, {:a 3} {:b 4}, {:a 5} {:b 1}, {:a 6} {:b 1}}
a2b-map => {{:a 1} {:b 2}, {:a 3} {:b 4}, {:a 5} {:b 1}, {:a 6} {:b 1}}

combine-keyvals-from-a2b-map
---------------------------------
cum-result => []
a2b-entry => [{:a 1} {:b 2}]
combined-ab-map => {:a 1, :b 2}
new-result => [{:a 1, :b 2}]

combine-keyvals-from-a2b-map
---------------------------------
cum-result => [{:a 1, :b 2}]
a2b-entry => [{:a 3} {:b 4}]
combined-ab-map => {:a 3, :b 4}
new-result => [{:a 1, :b 2} {:a 3, :b 4}]

combine-keyvals-from-a2b-map
---------------------------------
cum-result => [{:a 1, :b 2} {:a 3, :b 4}]
a2b-entry => [{:a 5} {:b 1}]
combined-ab-map => {:a 5, :b 1}
new-result => [{:a 1, :b 2} {:a 3, :b 4} {:a 5, :b 1}]

combine-keyvals-from-a2b-map
---------------------------------
cum-result => [{:a 1, :b 2} {:a 3, :b 4} {:a 5, :b 1}]
a2b-entry => [{:a 6} {:b 1}]
combined-ab-map => {:a 6, :b 1}
new-result => [{:a 1, :b 2} {:a 3, :b 4} {:a 5, :b 1} {:a 6, :b 1}]
a-and-b-map => [{:a 1, :b 2} {:a 3, :b 4} {:a 5, :b 1} {:a 6, :b 1}]
```

In hindsight, it could be simplified more if we were guarenteed that each input map was like {:a  :b }, since we could simplify it to a series of 2-d points like [n m], since the keywords `:a` and `:b` would be reduntant.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a better answer using the `group-by` function:

```
(ns clj.core
  (:use tupelo.core)
  (:require [clojure.core               :as clj]
            [schema.core                :as s]
            [tupelo.types               :as tt]
            [tupelo.schema              :as ts]
  ))

; Prismatic Schema type definitions
(s/set-fn-validation! true)   ; #todo add to Schema docs

(def data [ {:a 1 :b 2} {:a 3 :b 4} {:a 1 :b 6} {:a 3 :b 9} {:a 5 :b 1} {:a 6 :b 1} ] )

(def data-by-a (group-by :a data))
    ; like { 1 [{:a 1, :b 2} {:a 1, :b 6}], 
    ;        3 [{:a 3, :b 4} {:a 3, :b 9}], 
    ;        5 [{:a 5, :b 1}],
    ;        6 [{:a 6, :b 1}] }
(spyx data-by-a)

(defn smallest-map-by-b
  [curr-result  ; like {:a 1, :b 2}
   next-value]  ; like {:a 1, :b 6}
  (if (<  (grab :b curr-result)
          (grab :b next-value))
    curr-result
    next-value))

(defn find-min-b
  "Return the map with the smallest b value"
  [ab-maps] ; like [ {:a 1, :b 2} {:a 1, :b 6} ]
  (reduce smallest-map-by-b 
          (first ab-maps)   ; choose 1st as init guess at result
          ab-maps))

(def result 
  (glue
    (for [entry data-by-a]  ; entry is MapEntry like:  [ 1 [{:a 1, :b 2} {:a 1, :b 6}] ]
      (spyx (find-min-b (val entry)))
      )))
(spyx result)

(defn -main [] )
```

which produces the result

```
data-by-a => {1 [{:a 1, :b 2} {:a 1, :b 6}], 3 [{:a 3, :b 4} {:a 3, :b 9}], 5 [{:a 5, :b 1}], 6 [{:a 6, :b 1}]}
(find-min-b (val entry)) => {:a 1, :b 2}
(find-min-b (val entry)) => {:a 3, :b 4}
(find-min-b (val entry)) => {:a 5, :b 1}
(find-min-b (val entry)) => {:a 6, :b 1}
result => [{:a 1, :b 2} {:a 3, :b 4} {:a 5, :b 1} {:a 6, :b 1}]
```